# Possible maps $(\mathbb Z[i]/\mathfrak p)^\times\to\mu_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\mathfrak p$ be a maximal ideal of $\mathbb Z[i]$ not dividing 2. Is it true that the only maps from the cyclic group $(\mathbb Z[i]/\mathfrak p)^\times$ the the fourth roots of unity are powers of the quartic reciprocity symbol (by the latter i mean the symbol $(\alpha/\pi)_4\equiv \alpha^{(N\pi-1)/4}\pmod\pi$)?

If $x$ is a generator for $(\mathbb Z[i]/\mathfrak p)^\times$ and $x\mapsto i^n\in\mu_4$ for some $n=0,1,2,3$, then I'd guess the map is given by $(\cdot/\mathfrak p)_4^n$?

Comment: What does "an ideal . . . not dividing $2$" mean? Cheers!

Comment: Just abuse of language meaning $(2)\not\subseteq\mathfrak p$ ;) For example, we do not want to consider $\mathfrak p=(1+i)$ since $(2)=(1+i)^2$.

Comment: OK, thanks for the speedy response.  Cheers!